# Remove duplicates with the same NAME and keep the one with a higher USER RATING COUNT. (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates, tuples

I have sorted a list of tuples by **name**, each tuple has the elements **id**, **name**, **average_rating**, **rating_count**, **developers**, and **size**.

I'm now trying to remove the duplicate **name** and only keep the one with the higher **rating_count**.

A snip of my sorted list of tuples

```
[(320469536, '4_IN_1_ROW_Lite', 2.5, 3593, 'AOBO Co.,Ltd', 7750656),
(299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 16, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352),
(299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 900, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352)
]
```

I would like an output of

```
[(320469536, '4_IN_1_ROW_Lite', 2.5, 3593, 'AOBO Co.,Ltd', 7750656),
(299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 900, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352)
]
```

only keeping '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55' with the highest ***rating_count*** which is 900.

My take

```
    for i in range(len(list_of_games)):
        if list_of_games[i][1] == list_of_games[i+1][1] and \
                list_of_games[i][3] > list_of_games[i+1][3]:
            list_of_games.remove(list_of_games[i+1])
        elif list_of_games[i][1] == list_of_games[i+1][1] and \
                list_of_games[i][3] < list_of_games[i+1][3]:
            list_of_games.remove(list_of_games[i])
```

But I got an out of range error

```
line 222, in main
    if list_of_games[i][1] == list_of_games[i+1][1] and \
IndexError: list index out of range
```

May I know how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over last the element. You got out of range, because by iterating over last element you are comparing it with last + 1th element, which doesn't exist.

This should solve it:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_games)-1):
        if list_of_games[i][1] == list_of_games[i+1][1] and \
                list_of_games[i][3] > list_of_games[i+1][3]:
            list_of_games.remove(list_of_games[i+1])
        elif list_of_games[i][1] == list_of_games[i+1][1] and \
                list_of_games[i][3] < list_of_games[i+1][3]:
            list_of_games.remove(list_of_games[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

First, sort the list of games by `id` (ASC), `average_rating` (DESC) and then use `groupby()` to remove the duplicates:

```py
from itertools import groupby

out = [
    next(g)
    for _, g in groupby(
        sorted(list_of_games, key=lambda g: (g[0], -g[3])), lambda g: g[0]
    )
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    (299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 900, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352), 
    (320469536, '4_IN_1_ROW_Lite', 2.5, 3593, 'AOBO Co.,Ltd', 7750656)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might tackle this by resorting the list by name and rating_count then adding the items to a dictionary with a key of name or id. Then you can take the values of that new dictionary.

```py
data_in = [
    (320469536, '4_IN_1_ROW_Lite', 2.5, 3593, 'AOBO Co.,Ltd', 7750656),
    (299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 16, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352),
    (299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 900, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352)
]

data_out = {x[1]: x for x in sorted(data_in, key=lambda x : (x[1], x[3]))}.values()
print(list(data_out))
```

gives you:

```
[
    (320469536, '4_IN_1_ROW_Lite', 2.5, 3593, 'AOBO Co.,Ltd', 7750656), 
    (299139129, '5x5 Shogi (MiniShogi) K55', 4.0, 900, 'Yoshikazu Kakinoki', 3940352)
]
```

If you don't care about preserving the ordering by name, you could also just sort by rating_count rather than name and rating count.